# How to dynamically add textviews in a linear layout with additional constraints?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app in which I want to add textviews in a column-wise order. Atmost 3 textviews can fill horizontally the screen width. If there are more than 3 textviews to be added, the new ones should be added in the next row, and so on. See the diagram below-

---1st---------------2nd--------------3rd

---4th----------------5th-----and so on

I know we need to use a nested linear layout with different orientation parameters. But how do I get around this "maximum 3 textviews per row constraint". I know that this has to do something with the *weight* parameter. The code I have written so far is-

```
LinearLayout out = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_params);
TextView mView = new TextView(this);
mView.setText("placeholder");
mView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
out.addView(mView);
```

And for the layout I have written-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/out
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
    
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/in
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView ... />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How should I modify the above xml and code so that I am able to place the views dynamically as required ?

Comment: Use gridview with number of columns set to 3 .Or you can dynamically calculate the size of the screen , divide into 3 (width of each text view)  and create Linear Layouts of total text views to be displayed divided by 3 . Add 3 text views of the width calculated as child of each linear layout .

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this will be to use a GridView Component with three columns. It will allow you to add the views as well.

If you use LinearLayout you will have to use weights and keep adding new LinearLayout per row, this will take a lot of processing for calculations and overdrawing as well.

Using GridView will help to avoid writing the code to calculate and add every row and every view and will keep the layout optimized as well.